# How to force validate data of the HTML 5 input from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, required

I do have a input with the pattern and the title to show the error in case of wrong data, I do need to not use the post method, so I just make some Jquery code to use the input validation, but I can't find how to show the default message of the input

This is the HTML5 input:

```
<input type="text" id="user" pattern="whatever pattern" title="wrong value" required>
```

And this is the jquery code:

```
    $("#inputEnviar").click(
    function(){

        var userValidation = $("#user")[0].checkValidity();

        //validate if the pattern match
        if ( userValidation ){

            //code to do whatever I have to do if the data is valid

        } else {
            //if the data is invalid
            //the input already has a default message to show
            //then, how do I force to show
            $("#user")-> FORCE TO SHOW TO THE DEFAULT ERROR MESSAGE OF THE INPUT
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the validation fails, in your `else` code block, set the custom message that you want to notify to the user:

```
$("#user")[0].setCustomValidity("Please enter at least 5 characters.");
```

Then, you can use [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) to show that message. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity):

> The `HTMLFormElement.reportValidity()` method returns `true` if the element's child controls satisfy their validation constraints. When `false` is returned, cancelable `invalid` events are fired for each invalid child and validation problems are reported to the user.

```js
$("#inputEnviar").click(
  function() {
    var userValidation = $("#user")[0].checkValidity();
    //validate if the pattern match
    if (userValidation) {
      //code to do whatever I have to do if the data is valid
    } else {
      $("#user")[0].setCustomValidity("Please enter at least 5 characters.");
      var isValid = $('#user')[0].reportValidity();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="user" pattern="whatever pattern" title="wrong value" required>

<input id="inputEnviar" type="button" value="Send">
```

For old browsers (i.e. IE) you would need to use a polyfill.
There are several implementations around (like this [git](https://gist.github.com/nuxodin/73a2c2423cbbf6818c28ad803985d5c7)). This [article](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/01/28/reportvalidity/) goes deeper on the topic.

Comment: It work, I just need to add custom message first using setCustomValidity("")

Comment: @Angel - Updated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The `reportValidity()` function will show the default message after you have set it with `setCustomValidity`.

```js
function send() {
    var input = $("#user")[0];
    input.setCustomValidity("");
    if(!input.checkValidity()) {
        input.setCustomValidity("watch me break");
        input.reportValidity();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="user" pattern="[^,]*" title="Message">
<button onclick="send()">Click</button>
```

Comment: but the message is not yet displayed

Comment: I believe I found your solution. You can try the snippet so that you can see it in action.